# How to access user info in nuxt/auth?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to access the data stored in local storage using function testData(), but for some reason my console prints out *{ob: Observer}*. I set the data inside function login() and I can also see it in my browser.

I'm new to front-end development, so I would appreciate any help.

`Vue`

```js
testData() {
  console.log(this.$auth.$storage.getUniversal('user'))
},

login() {
  this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
    data: { 
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }
  }).then(response => {
    const user = response.data
    this.$auth.setUser(user)
    this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal('user', user.username, true)
  })
},
```

`localStorage`

[image]

Comment: Well, I guess I can always display data using localStorage.getItem('auth.user')

Comment: Yep, reaching for it can also be done this way but I guess that OP tries to follow the module practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `nuxt/auth` user with `this.$auth.$storage.state.user` properly (or even `this.$auth.user`).
When you see `Observer`, it just means that it's watching for your data but the object is currently empty, it's actually a **getter**.

I've tried to refresh and in that case, this is indeed empty.

But if you logout and log back in, or just log in as usually and check the value via a button or alike, you'll see it populated with `email` and `password`.

Meanwhile, I'm not sure that `this.$auth.$storage.setUniversal('user', user.username, true)` is needed because the module is doing that for you.
What are you actually want to do here?